# PHP configure on Windows: Enable libxml2

Tags: php, c++, libxml2

I am compiling libxml2 and php on my own on Windows. But somehow, libxml is not enabled in PHP. I am doing this:

1) I am compiling libxml2 static. This is done with the help of a build script. I am compiling libxml2 four time: (x32/x64) and (release/debug). I will show here one part of the build script for x32 / release, where you can see how libxml2 is compiled:

```
cscript configure.js prefix=%WORKD_IR% include="%ICONV_INCLUDE_DIR%" lib="%ICONV_LIB_DIR_32%" static=yes debug=no
nmake /f Makefile.msvc
robocopy "bin.msvc" "%BIN32_DIR%" *.dll *.exe
robocopy "bin.msvc" "%LIB32_DIR%" *.lib
```

2) In the build script, for compiling php 5.6.20, I add the library and include directory for libxml2 through the `configure` parameter `--with-extra-includes` and `--with-extra-libs`. And, I also added these parameters to the script `configure`:

```
    ...
    --with-libxml=static^
    --with-simplexml=static^
    --enable-xmlreader^
    --with-dom^
```

But somehow, when I look at the output of the build script, I see, that libxml is not enabled:

```
...
WARNING: dom support can't be enabled, libxml is not enabled
...
WARNING: soap not enabled, libxml not found
...
```

So, why libxml2 is not enabled? What I am missing here? They are all compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

When starting `configure` script, the flag for libxml should be like this:

```
...
--with-libxml^
...
```